# Undefined method 'resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError) in config\routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Undefined method 'resources' for main:Object (NoMethodError) in
>   config\routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: Is that the full code of `routes.rb?`

Comment: Please have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a block around it:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```